# Код WordPress добавления атрибутов ширины и высоты некорректно работает при отсутствии картинки

Tags: php, wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста. 
Почерпнул вот здесь https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236318/insert-width-height-attributes-to-all-images-displayed-on-each-page отличный код, который добавляет ширину и высоту картинкам, что вставлены в статью.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_image_dimensions' );

function add_image_dimensions( $content ) {

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);

    if (count($images) < 1)
        return $content;

    foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
        preg_match_all( '/(alt|title|src|width|class|id|height)=("[^"]*")/i', $image, $img );

        if ( !in_array( 'src', $img[1] ) )
            continue;

        if ( !in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || !in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ) {
            $src = $img[2][ array_search('src', $img[1]) ];
            $alt = in_array( 'alt', $img[1] ) ? ' alt=' . $img[2][ array_search('alt', $img[1]) ] : '';
            $title = in_array( 'title', $img[1] ) ? ' title=' . $img[2][ array_search('title', $img[1]) ] : '';
            $class = in_array( 'class', $img[1] ) ? ' class=' . $img[2][ array_search('class', $img[1]) ] : '';
            $id = in_array( 'id', $img[1] ) ? ' id=' . $img[2][ array_search('id', $img[1]) ] : '';
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( str_replace( "\"", "" , $src ) );

            $image_tag = sprintf( '<img src=%s%s%s%s%s width="%d" height="%d" />', $src, $alt, $title, $class, $id, $width, $height );
            $content = str_replace($image, $image_tag, $content);
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Единственное, если картинка недоступна (к примеру, она находится на другом сайте) в момент загрузки, то ей устанавливается `width="0"` и `height="0"`, что совсем нехорошо, потому что используемый кеширующий плагин в WP кеширует страницу и даже при возобновлении доступности картинки она будет скрыта.

Как исключить добавление «нулевых» атрибутов width и height, если картинка недоступна в момент формирования страницы?

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: ну дак есть же у вас `$width` и `$height` которые выводятся в значения атрибутов. Вот и проверьте, больше они 0 или нет. Если нет, то нет и выводить не надо.

Comment: Я в программировании разбираюсь чуть чуть только. знаю только как добавить if и добавить условие. Но тут я даже не знаю куда его можно вставить :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил необходимо условие

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_image_dimensions' );

function add_image_dimensions( $content ) {

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);

    if (count($images) < 1)
        return $content;

foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
    preg_match_all( '/(alt|title|src|width|class|id|height)=("[^"]*")/i', $image, $img );

    if ( !in_array( 'src', $img[1] ) )
        continue;

    if ( !in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || !in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ) {
        $src = $img[2][ array_search('src', $img[1]) ];
        $alt = in_array( 'alt', $img[1] ) ? ' alt=' . $img[2][ array_search('alt', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $title = in_array( 'title', $img[1] ) ? ' title=' . $img[2][ array_search('title', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $class = in_array( 'class', $img[1] ) ? ' class=' . $img[2][ array_search('class', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $id = in_array( 'id', $img[1] ) ? ' id=' . $img[2][ array_search('id', $img[1]) ] : '';

        list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( str_replace( "\"", "" , $src ) );
        $html = '';

        if (($width != 0) || ($height != 0)) {
            $html = ' width="%d" height="%d" ';
        }

        $image_tag = sprintf( '<img src=%s%s%s%s%s' . $html . '/>', $src, $alt, $title, $class, $id, $width, $height );
        $content = str_replace($image, $image_tag, $content);
    }
}

return $content;
}
```

Comment: Низкий поклон. Работает превосходно :-)